# How to present the statistical significance of changes for time series

Tags: time-series, statistical-significance, confidence-interval

I am very new to time series analysis and I couldn't find a satisfying answer on other posts about statistical significance.
I have 3 times series for 3 distinct stations. Each of them corresponds to an average of 3 distinct measurements and display a striking, coherent change.
I am asked to present the statistical significance of this change (not to run a significance test) with at least 95% confidence limits on my plots.
My  biggest problem is that I am not 100% sure I understand what is expected from me ,and I only one shot to do this. Does that mean I should put the confidence interval based on the measurements used in the average?